# open listview when click button

Tags: android

i want to do something that when i click on button he will openfor me something like listview with the name of all the contacts in my phone...how can i do it?
i know how to get the names of all the contacts in my phone and put them into string array,however how can i open a new windows with a listview of all the contacts name when i click on button?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first Activity when you click on button:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactsActivity.class));
```

Then in your ContactsActivity:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);

            ListAdapter adapter = createAdapter();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        /**
         * Creates and returns a list adapter for the current list activity
         * @return
         */
        protected ListAdapter createAdapter()
        {
            // List with strings of contacts name
            contactList = ... someMethod to get your list ...

            // Create a simple array adapter (of type string) with the test values
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);

            return adapter;
        }
    }
```

XML file for  your ContactsActivity (name it to contacts_view.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
     <ListView  
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />
     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Empty set"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks! and what is the xml file that i need to create? and from the main_activity in i need to write: "new ContactsActivity" in order to open the listactivity window when i click on the button?

Comment: ok,thank i understand it..and as i understand from your code that i need to create an xml file called : "simple_list_item_1"..what do i need to implement in this xml file? thanks in advance

Comment: ohh no, that simple_list_item_1 is a built in xml file from android :)

Comment: when you see "android.R.layout" before the xml name, it means it's the android's xml files.

Comment: I have inserted now the full code for you, just copy and paste it. Then in your res/layout create this file called "contacts_view.xml" and paste XML code in there.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a listActivity

[listActivity on android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: thanks,can you give me an example how can i do it programmatically?thanks

Comment: In the link above you have a small example, in http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/ is the same (think) but explained better

Answer (score 0):

On the button click you need to start new Activity(or ListActivity) that contains list of all contacts.So you need to set `onClicklistener` then in `onClick` function you need to write code for starting Activity

On second activity Create a CustomAdapter that will initialised with say List

```
class Contact
{
    private String number;
    private String name
}
```

Thanks.