# ListView loads with no data-Android

Tags: android, android-listview

**MessagesActivity.java**

```
package org.example.fbapp;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MessagesActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "549603678442054";
    ListAdapter adapter;
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    // data JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ListView lv;

    ListView mylistview;
    ArrayList<String> array_months;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        ListAdapter adapter = createAdapter();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns a list adapter for the current list activity
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected ListAdapter createAdapter()
    {
        mAsyncRunner.request("203153109726651/feed", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("GET POSTS", response);
                String json = response;

                try {

                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray finalObj = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                    array_months = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < finalObj.length(); i++) {

                        final String message = finalObj.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("message");

                        array_months.add(message);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Name: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        });
                    }

                    // Create a simple array adapter (of type string) with the test values
                    //ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapter);
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MessagesActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_months);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });


        //setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

**FBAppActivity.java**

```
package org.example.fbapp;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FBAppActivity extends Activity {

    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "549603678442054";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    // data JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ListView lv;
    // Buttons
    Button btnFbLogin;
    Button btnFbGetProfile;
    Button btnPostToWall;
    Button btnShowAccessTokens;
    Button btnFbLogout;
    Button btnGetPost;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbapp);

        // facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
        btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
        btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
        btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);
        btnFbLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btnGetPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_group_posts);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);




        /**
         * Login button Click event
         * */
        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
                loginToFacebook();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Logout button Click event
         * */
        btnFbLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Logout Button", "button Clicked");
                logoutFromFacebook();
            }
        });
        /**
         * Getting facebook Profile info
         * */
        btnFbGetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getProfileInformation();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Posting to Facebook Wall
         * */
        btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postToWall();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Get Posts from Group
         * */
        btnGetPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // getGroupPosts();
                //getGPosts();

                startActivity(new Intent(FBAppActivity.this, MessagesActivity.class));
            }
        });

        /**
         * Showing Access Tokens
         * */
        btnShowAccessTokens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAccessTokens();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making post to wall visible
            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making show access tokens button visible
            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making logout button visible
            btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making group posts button visible
            btnGetPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream",
                    "user_groups" }, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires",
                            facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();

                    // Making Login button invisible
                    btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    // Making logout Button visible
                    btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Making post to wall visible
                    btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Making show access tokens button visible
                    btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Making logout button visible
                    btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Making group posts button visible
                    btnGetPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error

                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors

                }

            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    JSONObject birthday = profile.getJSONObject("location");

                    final String location = birthday.getString("name");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email
                                            + "\nLocation: " + location,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get Group Posts by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getGPosts() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("203153109726651/feed", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("GET POSTS", response);
                String json = response;

                try {

                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray finalObj = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < finalObj.length(); i++) {

                        final String message = finalObj.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("message");

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        messages.add(map);


                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Name: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        });
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FBAppActivity.this, messages,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name });
        //FBAppActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Function to post to facebook wall
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to show Access Tokens
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAccessTokens() {
        String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Function to Logout user from Facebook
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // make Login button visible
                            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // making all remaining buttons invisible
                            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnGetPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fbapp, menu); return true; }
     */

}
```

When i click on the button, the `ListView` opens but with no data i.e. `Empty set`.

**Contacts_View.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
     <ListView  
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />
     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Empty set"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```

What i mean here is that both the functions are identical.`getGPosts()` is called in the `FBAppActivity` whereas the `createAdapter()` is called in `MessagesActivity`.`getGPosts()` works but `createAdapter()` does not. Kindly help me understand why is this happening.

Basically i am trying to import posts from a facebook group. My `Toast object` is working fine from the `getGPosts()` [it is in the FBAppActivity class] function. This function `getGPosts()` is called on the button click.I verified that i am getting the data using the `Toast object`. Now i want to populate the data to a `ListView`. Which i am unable to do. I have tried various methods, but none has worked out for me.

Comment: I would suggest that you put more explanation into your problem, etc. Roughly 90% of your post is code.

Comment: I noticed just now tha we can't see how you initialized `messages` ArrayList. Perhaps it is an attribute of the FBAppActivity and that's why it works for that one, but not for the ListActivity. Could you also post that part of code?

Comment: @NitroNbg I have added the `FBAppActivity` class also to the question.Basically i am trying to import posts from a facebook group. My Toast object is working fine from the getGPosts() [it is in the  `FBAppActivity` class] function. This function getGPosts() is called on the button click.I verified that i am getting the data using the Toast object. Now i want to populate the data to a ListView. Which i am unable to do. I have tried various methods, but none has worked out for me.

Comment: The problem is that when you invoke the new Activity (MessageActivity) you lose the credentials that you've presumably acquired in the login methods of the FBAppActivity. That's why the ListView doesn't get populated because the Facebook Graph rejects the request from your application.

Comment: @NitroNbg So what is the solution ? Cannot i populate the `ListView` from the `FBAppActivity` class?

Comment: You could populate the ArrayList in the FBAppActivity and then parse it to the MessageActivity via `Intent.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)` and then inside the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the MessageActivity retreive that Array via `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(String name)` and use that Array to initialize the listAdapter. Finally use setListAdapter(listAdapter) to populate the ListView.

Comment: Sorry, i am unable to understand. Can you give me the complete code?

Comment: Where do i use this `Intent.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)` in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling the `setListAdapter(adapter)` for implicit (Activity's) ListView in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method and in the `getGPosts()` method you reference the correct (visible) ListView.
Simply change the mentioned call in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method to:

```
myListView = getListView();
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And you should be fine! Good luck!

P.S. This solution will work if your ListActivity follows the following requirement:

> your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"

from [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: I get this error `The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type ListView` for `setListAdapter`

Comment: Sorry it's just setAdapter(adapter), it was my semantic error

Comment: Sorry no luck. I still get an empty `ListView`

Comment: Why don't i get any message? `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Name: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        });` Why isn't this code executing?

Comment: As for the ListView, are you sure that the xml file you're using to inflate the view in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` has a ListView element?
As for the Toast object I see nothing wrong with your code, it should work fine.

Comment: It is not XML, it's a JSON object from facebook. I am trying to import posts from a facebook group. And in `getGPosts()` function my Toast object works fine but not in the `createAdapter()` function.

Comment: I was reffering to this line: `setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);` by Android compiler, the Layout that your ListActivity uses *MUST* have a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" in order for methods like `getListView()` or `setListAdapter(adapter)` to work properly

Comment: I have added the `contacts_view.xml` to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are extending ListActivity. So below code must throw a NPE.

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should use below code at `onComplete` method instead;

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

or

```
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake i forgot to comment out those lines. Basically i am trying to import posts from a facebook group. My Toast object is working fine from the `getGPosts()` function. This function `getGPosts()` is called on the button click. Now i want to populate the data to a `ListView`. Which i am unable to do. I have tried various methods, but none has worked out for me. [Link to tutorial i followed] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562761/open-listview-when-click-button)

Comment: This is the error that i get `The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener(){}`

Comment: setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is a method of ListActivity class so you can only call it on objects of that type.

Comment: Use MessagesActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter)

Comment: `The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type FBAppActivity`

Comment: I have two classes , the `getGPosts()` function is in the `FBAppActivity` class.

Comment: Then you have to return array from getGPosts method and create your adapter where you called getGPosts from your MessagesActivity.

Comment: Can you please check again?  I have added the FBAppActivity class also to the question.Basically i am trying to import posts from a facebook group. My Toast object is working fine from the getGPosts() [it is in the FBAppActivity class] function. This function getGPosts() is called on the button click.I verified that i am getting the data using the Toast object. Now i want to populate the data to a ListView. Which i am unable to do. I have tried various methods, but none has worked out for me.

Comment: Could you please try to add MessagesActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter) under onComplete method(after your adapter creation). That must work if you are getting  the data.